# How code below the finally block execute?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I couldn't find any Microsoft official resource that shows how code below the finally block execute, the only information in regards to it is the book CLR via C#, the author says:

> Code below the finally block executes if no exception is thrown within the try block or if a catch block catches the exception and doesn't throw or re-throw an exception.

Let's say we have the following code:

```
class Program {
   static void Main(string[] args) {
      SomeMethod1();
      Console.ReadLine();
   }

   static void SomeMethod1() {
      try {
         SomeMethod2();
      }
      finally {
         Console.WriteLine("SomeMethod1 finally");
      }
      Console.WriteLine("SomeMethod1 last");
   }

   static void SomeMethod2() {
      try {
         SomeMethod3();
      }
      catch (DivideByZeroException e) {
         Console.WriteLine("SomeMethod2 caught");
      }
      finally {
         Console.WriteLine("SomeMethod2 finally");
      }
      Console.WriteLine("SomeMethod2 last");
   }

   static void SomeMethod3() {
      try {
         SomeMethod4();
      }
      finally {
         Console.WriteLine("SomeMethod3 finally");
      }
      Console.WriteLine("SomeMethod3 last");
   }

   static void SomeMethod4() {
      try {
         Int32 i = 0;
         var c = 3 / i;
      }
      finally {
         Console.WriteLine("SomeMethod4 finally");
      }
      Console.WriteLine("SomeMethod4 last");
   }
}
```

and the output is:

```
SomeMethod4 finally
SomeMethod3 finally
SomeMethod2 caught
SomeMethod2 finally
SomeMethod2 last
SomeMethod1 finally
SomeMethod1 last
```

You can see that "SomeMethod4 last" and "SomeMethod3 last" doesn't get printed.
"SomeMethod4 last" doesn't get printed is easy to understand as `SomeMethod4` throw an exception and there is no catch block to catch the exception, so it doesn't meet the requirement that specified by the author, fair enough.

But why "SomeMethod3 last" doesn't get printed? there is no exception thrown at `SomeMethod3`, just like `SomeMethod1`, so why "SomeMethod1 last" get printed while "SomeMethod3 last" doesn't? Is any Microsoft official resource that explain the mechanics of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the exception is thrown in `SomeMethod4`, it is flowing up to the calling method which is `SomeMethod3`. Think of it as if `SomeMethod4` was actually inline inside `SomeMethod3` like this.

```
    static void SomeMethod3()
    {
        try
        {
            try
            {
                Int32 i = 0;
                var c = 3 / i;
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SomeMethod4 finally");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("SomeMethod4 last");
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SomeMethod3 finally");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("SomeMethod3 last");
    }
```

The reason `SomeMethod2` Last is being run is because it is the part that actually catches the exception.

If you add a catch to `SomeMethod3`, you will see that `SomeMethod3 Last` gets printed as well.

Exceptions break the flow of the application, and basically don't stop going back up the call stack until it reaches a catch statement. Technically the exception is being thrown inside `SomeMethod1`, but its being caught in `SomeMethod2` which means the exception never reaches `SomeMethod1`.

Comment: @Lopop thanks for your answer, but why "SomeMethod1 last" get printed?

Comment: @amjad I made an edit to the end of my post which might have been too late. But the reason is because SomeMethod2 is catching the exception. Once an exception is caught it wont keep on going up the call stack. By catching it like you have, you're effectively saying "I can handle this, don't let anyone else know this exception happened", so that's why SomeMethod1 isn't effected by that exception.

Comment: thank you. I see now, but don't understand why there is no any official Microsoft resources mention it, all their examples don't have code below the finally block.

Comment: Take a look at this doc here... While they don't add any code below the finally they do include a comment that references more code being run after the finally.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch-finally